# How to replace a character within a string with fillPolygon using array

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace, applet

I am required to enter a word/sentence into a text box and then print out what I have input, however when I have a special character it will print out my fillPolygon shape. 
I have used an array to try and replace the character with the polygon using an If statement, however I keep on getting the error message:

```
[line: 49]  Error: method drawH in class Stringpoly cannot be applied to given types;  required: java.awt.Graphics,int,int  found:
java.awt.Graphics,int[],int[]  reason: actual argument int[] cannot be
converted to int by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: Please don't include "Thank you in advance" in your question. Our style focuses on the question, not on pleasantries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `int` array arguments in your `drawH` method to match the values being passed in. Replace

```
public void drawH(Graphics g, int xpoints, int ypoints)
```

with

```
public void drawH(Graphics g, int[] xpoints, int[] ypoints)
```

Another error is:

The arguments for `drawString` do not match any available versions of the method:

```
g.drawString(pr_charArray[i]);
```

Look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) for this method. You need something like

```
g.drawString(new String(pr_charArray), xpos, ypos);
```

Another issue is that you don't instantiate or add the `pr_text` `TextField` in `init`. You could do:

```
pr_text = new TextField(20);
add(pr_text);
```

**Some Side Notes:**

- Java uses camel-case which would make `pr_text` `prText`
- `AWT` is incredibly old. Consider using the lightweight [Swing graphics library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

There are some layout issues to sort out - I will leave this as an exercise :)

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the code, and it now compiles, however when I enter text within the compiler lines and lines of red error messages appear? Do you have any ideas? Thanks